# White font on white background in dialog only on HTC desire series

Tags: android

My app shows white font on white background in fragment dialog only on HTC desire series phone. Other device shows proper black font on white background. How to resolve this issue. Please Help.

```
    private void adjustResourceLightness() {
            // change up button to light version if using dark theme
            int color = 0xFFFFFF;
            getActivity().setTheme(0);
            final Resources.Theme theme = getActivity().getTheme();

            if (theme != null) {
                TypedArray backgroundAttributes = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.colorBackground});

                if (backgroundAttributes != null) {
                    color = backgroundAttributes.getColor(0, 0xFFFFFF);
                    backgroundAttributes.recycle();
                }
            }

            // convert to greyscale and check if < 128
            if (color != 0xFFFFFF && 0.21 * Color.red(color) +
                    0.72 * Color.green(color) +
                    0.07 * Color.blue(color) < 128) {
                mBtnNavUp.setImageResource(R.drawable.navigation_up_light);
                mBtnCreateFolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_create_light);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug with htc. You must be using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
try setting 
context.setTheme(0) before calling context.getTheme().setTo(widgetTheme)

Comment: I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and add context.setTheme(0)  before calling context.getTheme().setTo(widgetTheme) as u told but its not working. Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: I am using this library for directory selection : https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser and this problem occur.

Comment: You need to do the similar fix for ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.PanelFeatureState.setStyle() also.

Comment: And one more thing you must be passing the base Context instead of just the Context to the object which is creating your widgets. If it doesn't solve your issue then please edit your question and show us your code.

Comment: I am using  github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser library and using dialog fragment from it.

Comment: I have seen you code but this is not what I was looking for. I want you to change theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to some other theme and see if it is having having same problem. Because I read it  in many places that its a bug in HTC phones with this theme. If it doesn't help then post code of xml file and your on create method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I have replaced Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Theme.AppCompat.Light and its working. But now problem is that my app showing dark font on dark actionbar.

Comment: change the text color with the attribute android:textColorPrimary

Comment: I think i need to change the text color of Actionbar from theme like this : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText